# Edit wiki tag is disabled sometimes

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I'm editing tags daily and sometimes as now I can't edit any tags.

I thought it's because of a maximum pending edits but it also happens hours after older tag wiki approved.

There's only messages:

> There is no usage guidance for this tag … yet!

But there's no edit button, is there another restriction or is it a bug?

for example [hazard](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hazard/info).

**EDIT**

This is not a cache issue
[image]

Comment: I do see a blue 'Propose Tag Info' button right now, could you check again?

Comment: Now I see, it is a cache issue?

Comment: I'm not sure. It could be that the suggested edit queue was full (but it's now at 87, so less likely), or you had already 5 pending suggested edits (also not likely if I read your question right). If someone else had a pending suggested edit on the tag wiki, you'd have seen this below the orange box.

Comment: @Glorfindel *If someone else had a pending suggested edit on the tag wiki, you'd have seen this below the orange box* I was wondering if this is true when there is no wiki yet at all.

Comment: @rene https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlbuilder/info has (at this moment) a pending wiki edit. It had a pending excerpt edit as well, which was shown as another link.

Comment: Why is this question closed? I am currently experiencing this issue on any tag wikis that I visit.

Comment: I agree, you can vote to reopen